# How to make a filter who isolate only lines in a view Revit api c#

Tags: c#, api, revit

I am trying to hide a certain type of text and lines in views. I could do it for the text but couldn't isolate the lines to hide them. Any idea about how I can filter the view for lines.

Answer (score 1):

Use [RevitLookup](https://github.com/jeremytammik/RevitLookup) to analyse what the elements you wish to hide look like through the API. Use a [FilteredElementCollector](http://www.revitapidocs.com/2017/263cf06b-98be-6f91-c4da-fb47d01688f3.htm) to retrieve the lines from the database. You can specify the view `ElementId` to retrieve lines displayed in your specific view. If any of these suggestions are unclear, work through the [Revit API getting started material](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/about-the-author.html#2) before doing anything else whatsoever.

Comment: Thank you Jeremy. I did                                                                   lineList = collector2.WherePasses(elementOwnerViewFilter2).OfClass(typeof(Line)).ToElements();                                                                                                                  but it didn't work. I got the error Autodesk.Revit.Exceptions.ArgumentException: The input type is not a subclass of Element.
Parameter name: type
   at Autodesk.Revit.DB.FilteredElementCollector.OfClass(Type type)

Comment: `Line` is a geometry element, not a Revit database element. Install RevitLookup. Use the 'snoop current selection' tool to explore what kind of database element the element you wish to retrieve really is. Without RevitLookup you are lost and will remain so forever.

Comment: I answered the same question in a little bit more depth in the Revit API discussion forum: https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/revit-api-forum/filter-to-isolate-lines-of-certain-type-i-a-view/m-p/7155650